# Javascript/Typescript - fill new Arr on a certain key from initial Arr

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, iterator

Following initial array has this values:
[image]

My Goal is to fill a new array that starts from the initial arr by the index where its name property is: 'Raged Barbarian'. I have the solution for this, but i think there is semantically a better way to approach this.

My approach is:

```
  public getNewArr(initialArr) {
    const newArr = [];
    let isRagedBarbarian: boolean = false;
    for (const troop of initialArr) {
      if (troop.name === 'Raged Barbarian') {
        isRagedBarbarian = true;
  }   if (isRagedBarbarian === true) {
        newArr.push(troop);
  }
}
```

Comment: what means fill? please add some data in text form to the question as well as the wanted result.

Comment: use array filter

Comment: Please don't post images of data or code: you're implicitly saying you expect us to *read the data and type it back out by hand* to test your scenario. That's a pain. Post it as text so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: dunno the problem, if it wasnt clear i wouldnt get a correct answer within a minute ;) dont comment if you dont want to solve a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `slice` + function `findIndex`.

```
const index = initialArr.findIndex(o => o.name === 'Raged Barbarian');
const newArr = initialArr.slice(Math.max(index, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) after obtaining the index like

```
public getNewArr(initialArr) {
    const index = initialArr.findIndex(troop => troop.name === 'Raged Barbarian');
    if(index > -1) {
       return initialArr.slice(index + 1);
    }
    return [];
}
```